# What is the average lifespan of Middle-earth creatures?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

Obviously, Elves are immortal and do not die of old age. But what of Hobbits, Dwarves, Men, and others? I would like to know the average lifespan of these three main races, along  with others you can  think of (e.g. Orcs/Goblins, Ents, Wargs, Great Eagles, Mirkwood Spiders).

Comment: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/16470/what-is-the-average-life-expectancy-of-middle-earth-inhabitants     http://lotrproject.com/statistics/#lifeexpectancy

Comment: I guess by spiders you mean Shelob. She does not have an average lifespan, she's a one of a kind. Or are you in fact interested in the lifespan of spiders, flies, beetles etc. on middle earth?

Comment: @Einer By spiders, I mean the Mirkwood Spiders that attacked the Company, and those like them.

Comment: @PartyKingThrandeezy: Lol, never mind me. Guess I need to read up on my silmarillion again ;-) Maybe the term "Mirkwood Spiders" instead of "Spiders" would make that clearer in your question though. You know, for halfbreeds like me.

Comment: Tuor is a man. He travels to the undying land and is made immortal. Since infinity times **any number** is still infinity, clearly the **average age of humans = infinity**.

Comment: Certain hobbits and at least one dwarf also went to the undying lands, but I think the spirit of the question is properly answered at LOTR Project.

Comment: @Richard Does one automatically become immortal when arriving in the Undying Lands, or by will of a higher power?

Comment: @PartyKingThrandeezy - Tolkien specifically said that you don't become immortal just by travelling to the undying lands. Eru made Tuor immortal; http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Eru_Il%C3%BAvatar

Comment: @Richard Infinity times 0 is 0.

Comment: @oldcat - touche, although zero isn't a number,  it's the absence of a number

Comment: @PartyKingThrandeezy That's one thing that always struck me: Men were supposedly given mortality as a gift, which I always thought was an eye-roller of a concept--sort of the ultimage white elephant, I guess.  But then Tuor is given immortality as a...gift or something?  So this special gift of mortality: Eru takes it away from Tuor as a gift?

Comment: Zero is a number; *infinity* is not. The limit of `n` times 0 as `n` increases is 0, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The very best answer is contained here: [LOTR Project: Life Expectancy](http://lotrproject.com/statistics/#lifeexpectancy)

This is a quick summary:

```
Dwarves: 194.5 years

Hobbits: 96.84 years

Numenorean Men & descendants: 237.2 years

Other Men: 81.85

Average for all Men: 163.41
```

Comment: Since this comes from lists of major characters and their ancestors, mostly kings, it is not a representative sample.

Comment: The average also seems quite näive, being simply (237 + 81)/2, rather than acknowledging the Numenorean royal line would be a *tiny* fraction of the global population.